# Cannot install OAuth extension in Xampp on Windows

Tags: php, oauth

I need to install oauth extension in php. I tried lot of ways but still I cannot get the oauth in my php. I mentioned below few steps to get oauth in PHP.

1. I copied the php_oauth.dll file to xampp/ext/
2. wrote this line `extension=php_oauth.dll` in php.ini
3. After restarting the server I accessed the phpinfo().php

But OAuth is not shown.

I can see this in my logfile:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oauth.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: There has to be a logfile somewhere ...

Comment: @Marged In my error log file i found that.PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oauth.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Add this to your question, check the file for correctness and Google the error message

Comment: okay @Marged I goolgle this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for this error. My system is 64 bit OS but XAMPP server installed in 32 bit. I install 64 bit oauth.dll file I cannot get oauth in PHP. After I install 32 bit oauth.dll I get the oauth in PHP file.(The windows binary and extension arch need to match)

Download link to php_oauth.dll - https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/1.2.3/windows

Comment: In the end it was easy, wasn't it ? ;-)

Comment: where I can find the 32 bit version. can you put any link to download

Comment: Added the download link.